# javascript/jquery - replace text with global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a documentation of an api which contains api endpoints, curl call syntax. It's a pure `html` document with `pre` and `blockquote` tags for code blocks. 
Currently the documnetation is for version 1.0. So the api calls are as below:

```
https://api.xxx.com/v1
```

Now we are going to release next version. And the url will be changed to `https://api.xxx.com/v1.1` and so on. It is very tidious to change all urls manually in the documentation. 
So I created a global variable as below and thought that only one change will reflect to all urls in documentation.

```
window._respapiurl = "https://api.xxx.com/v1";
```

My way is to change version number in a variable so it will work for all the urls.

And tried to replace it in a `pre` tag as `<pre class="highlight plaintext"><script>window._respapiurl</script></pre>`. But it didn't work due to the behaviour of `pre` tag.

**How do replace all the urls in documentation with global variable ???**

Comment: Why don't you just populate the `<pre>` tag at load time? I suppose `document.write(window._respapiurl);` would work, though.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use some setting file in PHP and set version url there, so you just change version variable.

```
$appVersion = '1.1';
echo "https://api.xxx.com/v{$appVersion}";
```

2) Use urls with placeholder, so you can loop and replace it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var appVersion = '1.1';

  $.each($("span.versionLink"), function() {
    var newText = $(this).text().replace("{version}", appVersion);
    $(this).text(newText);
  });

  $.each($("a.versionLink"), function() {
    var newLink = $(this).attr("href").replace("{version}", appVersion);
    $(this).attr("href", newLink)
  });
});

<pre>
  <span class="versionLink">https://app/v{version}</span>
  <a href="https://app/v{version}" class="versionLink">Link to another documentation</a>
</pre>
```